# Pytorch Operation to detect NaNs

Tags: python, pytorch

Is there a Pytorch-internal procedure to detect `NaN`s in Tensors? Tensorflow has the `tf.is_nan` and the `tf.check_numerics` operations ... Does Pytorch have something similar, somewhere? I could not find something like this in the docs...

I am looking specifically for a Pytorch internal routine, since I would like this to happen on the GPU as well as on the CPU. This excludes numpy - based solutions (like `np.isnan(sometensor.numpy()).any()`) ...

Comment: this might be of help: `x.isnan().any()`

Comment: For those who would also want to capture infinities, use  torch.all(torch.isfinite(tensor))

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can always leverage the fact that `nan != nan`:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([1, 2, np.nan])
tensor([  1.,   2., nan.])
>>> x != x
tensor([ 0,  0,  1], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

With pytorch 0.4 there is also [`torch.isnan`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=isnan#torch.isnan):

```
>>> torch.isnan(x)
tensor([ 0,  0,  1], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

Comment: I can confirm that it works on the GPU as well. `.any()` will then reduce it to a Python bool. Thank you :-)

Comment: Wow! I didn't know `nan != nan`. Thanks!

Answer (score 43):

Starting with PyTorch 0.4.1 there is the [`detect_anomaly`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.detect_anomaly) context manager, which automatically inserts assertions equivalent to `assert not torch.isnan(grad).any()` between all steps of backward propagation. It's very useful when issues arise during backward pass.

Answer (score 31):

As suggested by @cleros in the comment on @nemo's answer, you can get this as a boolean using the `any()` operator:

```py
torch.isnan(your_tensor).any()
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to call it on a tensor directly:

```
import torch

x = torch.randn(5, 4)
print(x.isnan().any())
```

out:

```
import torch
x = torch.randn(5, 4)
print(x.isnan().any())
tensor(False)
```

Answer (score 4):

True if any value is nan:

```
torch.any(tensor.isnan())
```

True if all is nan:

```
torch.all(tensor.isnan())
```